# How can I remove the Window dropdown in MenuBar?

Tags: wxpython

The wx.MenuBar class auto generates a Window dropdown that contains the entries: next, prev, close, and close all. How can I remove this option?

Comment: Can you be more specific and do you have example code. Even if you're subclassing `wx.MenuBar`, it should only insert menu entries that it's told to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I was using `wx.aui.AuiMDIParentFrame`, and it appends a Window menu item by default unless you use `wx.FRAME_NO_WINDOW_MENU` style option in the constructor.

Comment: And that is why questions should include code. With code, the issue would have been addressable, if not obvious, without it, who could have guessed, let alone provided a solution?

Comment: As far as I could tell, the use of the MenuBar API was completely generic. I wouldn't have included the enclosing wx.aui.AuiMDIParentFrame class definition even if I were to post a code sample, since it didn't make sense to me that wx.aui.AuiMDIParentFrame could affect an unrelated class without explicitly invoking its API.

Comment: There is reason behind the madness of `How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example` which so many posters seem unaware of, in their haste to get an answer. `Namely` to receive an appropriate and timely answer. I'm not "having a go" at you here, it will help for any future questions that you have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example